# Calling an external AS400 stored procedure from C# with output parameter

Tags: c#, sql, .net, stored-procedures, ibm-midrange

My stored procedure has 4 parameters: 3 strings as input and one string as output.

```
using (OdbcConnection cn = ODBC.Instance.AmulibConnection)
{
    cn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand cm = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cm.CommandText = "CALL RET_IMPL_STS('?','?','?','?')";
        cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cm.Parameters.Add("@P1", OdbcType.Char).Value = "1";
        cm.Parameters["@P1"].Size = 1;
        cm.Parameters["@P1"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cm.Parameters.Add("@P2", OdbcType.Char).Value = "ABC";
        cm.Parameters["@P2"].Size = 15;
        cm.Parameters["@P2"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cm.Parameters.Add("@P3", OdbcType.Char).Value = "DEF";
        cm.Parameters["@P3"].Size = 6;
        cm.Parameters["@P3"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

        cm.Parameters.Add("@P4", OdbcType.Char);
        cm.Parameters["@P4"].Size = 5;
        cm.Parameters["@P4"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cm.Prepare();
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        string result = cm.Parameters["@P4"].Value.ToString();

        return result;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> Additional information: ERROR [HY000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0469 - IN, OUT, or INOUT not valid for parameter 4 in procedure RET_IMPL_STS in *N.

What is the correct syntax for the output parameter?

Comment: have you tried https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.parameterdirection(v=vs.110).aspx  inout or return type parameter

Comment: Do you have an answer yet? If not, we'll probably need to know how the stored proc is defined in order to determine why SQL0469 is being returned.

Comment: Yes, I have. It was a syntax issue, please see the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following are 2 possible options:

1. We need to remove the quotes even if the parameters are string:

   cm.CommandText = "CALL RET_IMPL_STS(?,?,?,?)";

   Then we need to specify each 4 parameters
2. The following syntax will also work fine:

   cm.CommandText = string.Format("CALL RET_IMPL_STS ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', ?)", STIDAD, ITNOAD, ITRVAD);

   In that case we need to specify only the output parameter. Note that in this such format, the quotes are required for string parameters.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use the IBM cwbx libary. This is a IBM lib that is created for interop programming between Desktop and IBM AS400.

Take a look at here: http://timtrott.co.uk/calling-ibm-iseries-rpg-programs-api-calls/
This tells you, how to call a procedure with parameters located on a IBM AS400 and return some values. Trust me, I already have accomplished this task and it worked.

The whole thing is just including the cwbx.dll file, creating a instance of a machine and programm object, filling these with `ProgrammParameters` (defining input, output AND inout-parameter) and calling it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using cwbx;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string result = string.Empty;

            StringConverter stringConverter = new StringConverterClass();

            // Define an AS400 system and connect to it
            AS400System system = new AS400System();
            system.Define("AS400");
            system.UserID = "USERNAME";
            system.Password = "PASSWORD";
            system.IPAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            system.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd);

            // Check the connection
            if (system.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceRemoteCmd) == 1)
            {
                // Create a program object and link to a system                
                cwbx.Program program = new cwbx.Program();
                program.LibraryName = "LIBRARY";
                program.ProgramName = "RPGPROG";
                program.system = system;

                // Sample parameter data
                char chrValue = '1';
                string strValue1 = "ABC";
                string strValue2 = "DEF";
                string outp = "";

                // Create a collection of parameters associated with the program
                ProgramParameters parameters = new ProgramParameters();

                parameters.Append("P1", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 1);
                parameters["P1"].Value = chrValue;

                parameters.Append("P2"), cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 3);
                parameters["P2"].Value = strValue1;

                parameters.Append("P3"), cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcInput, 3);
                parameters["P3"].Value = strValue1;

                parameters.Append("P4", cwbrcParameterTypeEnum.cwbrcOutput, 3);


                outp = stringConverter.FromBytes(parameters["P4"].Value);
            }

            system.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

This should almost work, you have to be carefull, since the interface dll is sensitive to false length of parameter. So if you want to transmit "TEXT" and provide a textlength of 3, then only "TEX" is transmitted.

Comment: my purpose was to found the correct syntax for the posted question. However, your post is very informative and interesting, upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Reading @Andrei's link I've found this paragraph:

> When a stored procedure returns a resultset, the output parameter(s)
>   and return value are not available until the resultset has been
>   accessed and closed. For example, if we omitted the line "dr.Close()"
>   in the second sample above, we would be unable to retrieve the values
>   for the output parameter and the return value.

Comment: I also tried this example, but the error occurred before in the execute line.

Comment: @ehh I've found an article in CodeProject. It's a class that encapsulates DB2 API. Maybe you can find more info there. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5532/DB-Access-Classes

Answer (score 0):

your should use dll ibm data provider for .net like [here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.doc/doc/t0011824.html)

But you can try to modify you code

```
OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("{CALL RET_IMPL_STS('?','?','?','?')}", cn);
....
cm.Parameters["@P4"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

Answer (score -1):

At first view, it seems like your are missing some curly braces. Try using the following command to create a new OdbcCommand object

```
OdbcCommand cm = new OdbcCommand("{CALL RET_IMPL_STS('?','?','?','?')}", cn);
```

Please read more at: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310130